# when i click button, i want redirect to 'dashboard' from 'login' if 'isAuth' is 'true', but the page not redirect?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Auth.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { login } from './Auth.redux'

// @connect(
//     state => state.auth,
//     {login}
// )
class Auth extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.isAuth ? <Redirect to='/dashboard' /> : null}
                <p>你没有权限查看,需要登录</p>
                <button onClick={this.props.login}>登录</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    }
}

const authCreators = {login}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, authCreators)(Auth)

// export default Auth
```

when i click `button`, i want redirect to `dashboard` from `login`, if `isAuth` is `true`.
[image]

now, `isAuth` is `true`, but page not redirect to `dashboard`, i'm not find reason.
i thought is, when click `button`, call `login()`, `login()` is Auth.redux actionCreators, because actionCreators return action type is `LOGIN`, then dispatch `login` action.

Auth.redux.js

```
const LOGIN = 'login'
const LOGOUT = 'logout'

const initialState = {
    isAuth: false,
    username: 'ok'
}

export function auth(state=initialState, action){
    //console.log(state)
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN:
            return {...state, isAuth: true}
        case LOGOUT:
            return {...state, isAuth: false}
        default:
            return state
    } 
}

export function login(){
    return {type: LOGIN}
}

export function logout(){
    return {type: LOGOUT}
}
```

dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import App from './App'
import {logout} from './Auth.redux'

function Two(){
    return <h2>two</h2>
}

function Three(){
    return <h2>Three</h2>
}

// @connect(
//     state => state.isAuth,
//     {logout}
// )
class Dashboard extends Component{
    render(){
        const redirectLogin = <Redirect to='/login'/>
        const app = (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/dashboard/'>one</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/dashboard/two'>two</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/dashboard/three'>three</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <Route exact path='/dashboard/' component={App}></Route>    
                <Route path='/dashboard/two' component={Two}></Route>
                <Route path='/dashboard/three' component={Three}></Route>
            </div>
        )
        return this.props.isAuth ? app : redirectLogin
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    }
}

const actionCreators = {logout}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Dashboard)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Auth` and `Dashboard` components, you checked `this.props.isAuth` but it will return `undefined` because there is only `auth` prop which is refering to `state.auth`.
So you need to check `this.props.auth.isAuth` if the auth is true or false.

Comment: thanks! i find error in `mapStatetoProps`, `isAuth` is `auth` property, so in `mapStateToProps` i should `isAuth: state.auth.isAuth`